# big pipe, design pattern or just a technology?

Tags: php, facebook, design-patterns

guys i just have 3 questions about big pipe which used in Facebook and implementation.

**is this a design pattern in your opinion or just a technology for decrease the requests response time ???**

**is there any website instead of [facebook blog](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/bigpipe-pipelining-web-pages-for-high-performance/389414033919) which could help me to implement this thing?**

i have a website with over 50K users at the time and i'm about to change the system and i'm gonna use web socket with node js.

**what do you suggest, is this reasonable to spend the time on big pipe or just use it as a regular way?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to switch to Sockets and NodeJS, why don't you use http://socket.io This should exactly do what you want to achieve.

> BigPipe breaks the page generation process into several stages:
>
> - Request parsing: web server parses and sanity checks the HTTP request.
> - Data fetching: web server fetches data from storage tier.
> - Markup generation: web server generates HTML markup for the response.
> - Network transport: the response is transferred from web server to browser.
> - CSS downloading: browser downloads CSS required by the page.
> - DOM tree construction and CSS styling: browser constructs DOM tree of the document, and then applies CSS rules on it.
> - JavaScript downloading: browser downloads JavaScript resources referenced by the page.
> - JavaScript execution: browser executes JavaScript code of the page.

Comment: your solution is really interesting and i used it for a simple chat research. but i wanted to know is this reasonable to follow the facebook solution or it's just waisting time???